# How to import the Sanford Midi Library?

Tags: unity, c#, music

I am trying to parse a MIDI file using the Sanford MIDI Toolkit. How do I use this toolkit? I found this link on Github:

https://github.com/tebjan/Sanford.Multimedia.Midi

I downloaded the .zip file and saved it on my desktop. Afterwards, how should I proceed? This may be a beginner question, but how do I start using this library?

Do I need to save it in a particular location in my computer? Ultimately I just want to be able to have access to the functions, properties, etc. of this library.

Comment: Have you [googled C# midi](https://www.google.ca/search?q=c%23+midi)? If so, what specific challenge have you encountered in implementing what you've found so far?

Comment: What problem have you encountered in adding it to your project? Edit your question to describe what you've done and where you're stuck, so that users here know what kind of help you need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I edited my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I figured it out.

In order to expose the methods and properties of the library, I copied the DLL file found in Sanford.Multimedia.Midi-master/Source/bin/Debug to the GAC folder and then added a reference to the DLL in my project.

Comment: So your question wasn't anything midi-specific at all? You just needed to know how to import a plugin? [In future, please start by reading the docs on the subject](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Plugins.html) — this doesn't seem to have been a problem that would require expert Q&A to solve.